# how to send email automatically using jsp/servlet at partcular time(10'clock in the morning) daily

Tags: java, tomcat, jakarta-ee

I want to send email automatically using j2ee at specific time daily if tomcat server is in on mode by fetching data from database

Comment: That is not what jsp/servlet is for. Read about quarz

Comment: I completed task successfully, thank u guys

Answer (score 1):

You can try with cron job

**Main.java**

```
public class Main{
   public static void main(String[] args){

     Timer t = new Timer();
     YourTask yourTask= new YourTask();
enter code here
     // This task is scheduled to run every 5 seconds

     t.scheduleAtFixedRate(yourTask, 0, 5000);
   }

}
```

**YourTask**

```
class YourTask extends TimerTask{

   public YourTask (){
     //Some stuffs
   }

   @Override
   public void run() {
//TODO
Your business logic
   }

}
```

As shown in above code ,you can call your business logic of specific time duration.

Here i had made call to that specific business logic on interval of 5 seconds.

For **Timer**  [timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html) and **TimerTask** [timertask](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TimerTask.html)

Comment: Time is not best practice if thread stops due to some exception it will not work instead should use ScheduledExecutorService

Comment: @gatisahu if thread stops due to some exception,we have to stop execution  otherwise main business logic would be affected.

Comment: no if it is a transient exception

Comment: Still we have to manage.

Comment: I don't think that is best practice for some exception you are stopping your service.So your service should be stop only in error where you can not recover

Comment: Yes in specific scenario we have to manage using  `try-catch`.

Comment: Also Timer is single threaded so there is more disadvantages associated with it.I have only highlight one

Comment: I completed task successfully, thank u guys

Answer (score 0):

You can use 3rd party library like [quartz-scheduler](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/) to schedule your tasks.

[Here](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.x/cookbook/DailyTrigger.html) you can check examples, how to create trigger that executes every day.

```
 trigger = newTrigger()
    .withIdentity("trigger3", "group1")
    .startNow()
    .withSchedule(dailyAtHourAndMinute(15, 0)) // fire every day at 15:00
    .build();
```

Comment: Thanks for quick reply @yaroslav , can u pls send me sample code of jsp/servlet with simple task

Comment: you asked about two different layers of source code. So, for servlet usage you can check any sample, for example: http://javabycode.com/java-frameworks/servlet-jsp/servlet-3-0-annotation-example.html, and in place where "doGet" method is executed, you can place your scheduler task (for example which I provided above, but don't forget to include quartz dependency for your project)

Comment: I completed task successfully, thank u guys

Comment: You are welcome. Please upvote and accept answer, if it helped for you

Answer (score 0):

Use a ScheduledExecutorService or as mentioned below third party lib like Quartz

```
private final ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
 scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(yourRunnable, 8, 8, TimeUnit.HOURS);
```